# transforming nonlinear matrix inequality to LMI

Tags: inequality, matrix-equations, nonlinear-optimization, linear-matrix-inequality

I faced some nonlinearity in my problems.
I need to check a matrix inequality condition in order to check the feasibility of designed controller through a continuous design problem.
My problem is that I need an LMI to be checked but my developed formula in NMI in a bad style, could anybody help me with transforming this NMI to LMI:
\
$x$: decision variables(unknown)
$P$: symmetric positive definite matrix(unknown)
The original NMI condition:
$$
A_0(x)PA_1(x)^\top+A_1(x)PA_0(x)^\top +a A_0(x)PA_0(x) <0
$$
but after using Schur complement I developed following inequality:
$$
M:=\left( \begin{array}{cc} A_0(x)PA_1(x)^\top+A_1(x)PA_0(x)^\top & A_0(x)^\top \\
A_0(x) & -aP^{-1} \end{array} \right)<0,
$$
meaning $M$ is negative definite.

another transformation of this MI is this with is some how relaxed but one nonlinear term is still left:
$$
N:=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & A_0(x)^\top/a+A_1(x)^\top \\
A_0(x)/a+A_1(x) & -aP^{-1} \end{array} \right)<0,
$$
this yields to this inequality:
$$
A_0(x)PA_1(x)^\top+A_1(x)PA_0(x)^\top +a^{(-1)} A_0(x)PA_0(x) + a A_1(x)PA_1(x)<0
$$

Comment: What does it mean to have a matrix $<0$?  Do you mean it's negative definite?  Or that all its entries are negative?  Or something else?

Comment: yes.i mean to be negetive definite. i got this style by SCHUR formulation.